# 3 coins and a die

Tags: probability

$D$ is a regular die. We define win as landing ${1,2}$ on the die. $Coin1$, $Coin2$ , $Coin3$ are tossed simultaneously with the die if we land a head from any coin we win regardless of the results of die.

${(1,H),(2,H),(3,H),(4,H),(5,H),(6,H),(1,T),(2,T),(3,T),(4,T),(5,T),(6,T)}$

If there was only one coin, probability of win = $2/3$.

i.e. $P(win(D,Coin1)) = P(win(D,Coin2)) = P(win(D,Coin3)) = 2/3$

Can we reach to the final answer from the above step?

I know how to solve the above problem. I am solving another problem and the above problem is an simplified instance of it. I am stuck at the step where I solved (D,1),(D,2),(D,3) 
and don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: This is not clear.  Are you saying that the only losses are "$>2$ on the die and $TTT$ from the coins"?

Comment: @lulu Yes. (>2,TTT) are the only losses.

Comment: If my interpretation is correct (very far from clear) then the probability of a loss is $\frac 46\times \frac 18=\frac 1{12}$. So the probability of a win is $\frac {11}{12}$. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Your interpretation is absolutely correct. But my real problem is not that straightforward. I am looking for solutions that builds somewhat like: We first solve (D,Coin1) then **add** Coin2 and then Coin3.

Comment: It's really not clear what you have in mind.  I suggest you edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can reach the same conclusion by using Inclusion/Exclusion. This is a very convoluted solution, but it still yields the same result.

$$P(\text{win}(D,Coin1,Coin2,Coin3)) = P(\text{win}(D,Coin1))+P(\text{win}(D,Coin2))+P(\text{win}(D,Coin3)) - P(\text{win}(D,Coin1)\cap \text{win}(D,Coin2)) - P(\text{win}(D,Coin1)\cap \text{win}(D,Coin3)) - P(\text{win}(D,Coin2)\cap \text{win}(D,Coin3))+P(\text{win}(D,Coin1)\cap\text{win}(D,Coin2)\cap\text{win}(D,Coin3))$$

$$P(\text{win}(D,Coin1)\cap\text{win}(D,Coin2)) = P(D<3\cup (D>2\cap Coin1=H\cap Coin2=H)) = \dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{2}{3}\cdot \dfrac{1}{4} = \dfrac{1}{2}$$

$$P(\text{win}(D,Coin1)\cap\text{win}(D,Coin2)\cap \text{win}(D,Coin3)) = P(D<3\cup (D>2\cap Coin1=H\cap Coin2=H\cap Coin3=H)) = \dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{2}{3}\cdot \dfrac{1}{8} = \dfrac{5}{12}$$

Total probability:

$$P(\text{win}(D,Coin1,Coin2,Coin3)) = \dfrac{2}{3}+\dfrac{2}{3}+\dfrac{2}{3}-\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{5}{12} = \dfrac{11}{12}$$

Comment: Thank You!  This is exactly what I wanted.